# what did i do wrong in this NSTimer and why is it giving me an error message?

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/60 
target:self 
selector:@selector(gameloop)         
userinfo:nil 
repeats:YES];
```

the error message says: "no known class method selectors for scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval..."

Answer (score 4):

It's `userInfo` not `userinfo`. Notice the capitalisation.